# Pass a List to a Validator , Conversion Error setting value '[]' for 'null Converter

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am new in JSF, and my question is realted to the Validator.  I have an FileUploader (primefaces) and a Form. when the Submit button is clicked , a method should check the DataTable inside of the Form and also a validator should check if any file has been uploaded via FileUploader. Hence, I have put a Hidden button which calls the validator.
In my Bean I have the  following getter and setter:

```
  public List<Attachment> getAttachmentList() {
        return attachmentList;
    }

    public void setAttachmentList(List<Attachment> attachmentList) {
        this.attachmentList= attachmentList;
    }
```

and then in my validator I have the following code:

```
@FacesValidator("uploadValidator")
public class uploadValidator implements Validator {

    public uploadValidator()  {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
        @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {

            FacesMessage msg = 
                new FacesMessage(" this is the uploader message.", 
                        "this is the uploader message.");
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
```

when I call the validator from my XHTML file (`<f:validator validatorId="uploadValidator" />`), in Primefaces growl message,  I recieve the error : 
**Conversion Error setting value '[]' for 'null Converter**

Here is XHTML code:

```
        <h:inputHidden id="hidenB" value="#{myBean.attachmentList}">
                        <f:validator validatorId="uploadValidator" />
                    </h:inputHidden>
```

I know the problem is when I pass value to "Object value" but i don't know how to resolve it.
In Validator I just need to know if the attachmentList is empty or not, while in myBean i do other things with attachmentList, How can I send just a boolean value to the Validator ? can I have another getter and setter that send a Boolean value ?? if yes then I don't need a converter 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please format your code properly before posting.

Comment: Post the relevant xhtml code.

Comment: Without seeing the xhtml code, I can tell you that you're missing a converter clearly from the error message

Comment: I added the relevant xhtml code

Comment: Yes you're missing your converter... The HTML output is nothing less or more than one big String. All Java objects are to represented in their String format. If you didn't specify a converter for a non-String and non-Number typed object, then just its toString() will be called.. you need to implement a list converter..

Comment: in Validator I just need to know if the attachmentList is empty or not, while in myBean i do other things with attachmentList, How can I send just a boolean value to the Validator ? can I have another getter and setter that send a Boolean value ?? if yes then I don't need a converter

Comment: @BalusC: Because it's the validator which is calles via xhtml and <f:validator> tag and the validator gets the Object Value, am I wrong? I am new in this subjcet that's why I am confused.

Comment: @BalusC: I have started to follow you few days ago from your blog and your posts here, as I have found out you are an expert in JSF and Java.
the question is this: I have an FileUploader (primefaces) and a Form.
when the Submit button is clicked , a method should check the DataTable inside of the Form and also a validator should check if any file has been uploaded via FileUploader. Hence, I have put a Hidden button which calls the validator.
Can you help me to solve this?